# Why isn't this working?

Tags: electricity, voltage

I just broke a 120mm computer fan in name of science and now I'm pissed; can anyone explain why this doesn't work? :

[image]

The battery should create a potential difference across the motor, causing the fan to spin up, right?

Answer (score 10):

firstly, you hooked up the red wire to negative and the black wire to positive--you got it backwards.

secondly, computer fans operate at 12V, so you are short of several batteries. with luck, some fans might start spinning at 7V .

Comment: Would it not spin very slowly however?

Comment: Also, if I spin the fan itself, will it create a PD?

Comment: the magnetic force produced from such a low EMF is surely not sufficient to overcome the inertia of the fan blades. but if you spun the blades manually, you might find that they spin for a while longer than if a battery wasnt hooked up at all--but with only 1.5V i'm doubtful it will be perceptible.

Comment: what about my other question?

Comment: see the 4 coils inside the rotor? those are in series, and connect to the controlling electronics with 2 wires. you need to tap those two if you want to use the fan as a generator--you cant use the red and black wires as those are inputs to the electronics.

Comment: what if i did a bit of re- wiring